# How to view data in text file in well organized form

Tags: linux, redhat

how to view data in text file  separated by a any separator like "|" in well organized form
i.e 
data of each field is aligned in a form like columns

example:

first field|second field

first field|second field

Example:

```
abduct|edge
abdfgdgdgdg|Saddam
```

It should appear like this:

```
abduct     |edge
abdfgdgdgdg|Saddam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store these values in myfile, then:

cat myfile|column -t -s\|